# When using require is unable to get the definition however using import gets the linked definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

[image: exec type is any]

[image: Able to res]

```
var exec = require('child_process') // exec type is any

import ch from 'child_process'; // ch type is child process
```

Why i am getting this difference in typescript project

Which one should prefer to use in the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` is a TypeScript feature and TypeScript knows how it works and how to read types from modules that are loaded with it.

`require` is a CommonJS feature and none of the above applies.

Comment: understood this concept. Thanks for the clarification , i tried using import and got the declarations however when i try to run this i get an error 

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module,?

so resolved the above error - by adding ' "type": "module", in tsconfig.json

however when i try to run again then i get an error 

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

how can i resole this issue

Comment: @MohitTalreja — By using a TypeScript compiler for your TypeScript instead of trying to run it with a JavaScript runtime.